# Store operation hour in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, schema

I have many offices in my database and each office has its own operation time (ex: from 7:00 to 17:00).

Should I store operation hours like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59747cfabb8dd11e30310a92"),
"name" : "CE",
"value" : "Compact Enterprise",
"operation_time_start": "7:00", -> string value
"operation_time_end": "17:00" -> string value
}
```

or try another approach?

Comment: Try another approach. Depending on how granular you need it's best to store as a numeric value which on available storage types is going to take 4-bytes at most as opposed to the 6-bytes minimum for a string. Minutes in a day fits with ease. So does seconds or milliseconds for that matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use an integer in the range 0 - 1440, each number being an increment of a minute. In this way you can use $gte and $lte in your queries
Example:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59747cfabb8dd11e30310a92"),
"name" : "CE",
"value" : "Compact Enterprise",
"operation_time_start": 420
"operation_time_end": 1020
}
```

As an additional suggestion, consider that the opening hours can be different according to the day of week, so maybe a better schema can be like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59747cfabb8dd11e30310a92"),
"name" : "CE",
"value" : "Compact Enterprise",
"operations: {
   "1": {start: 420, end: 1020 },   -> operation time for dayOfWeek = 1
   "2": {start: 420, end: 1020 },   -> operation time for dayOfWeek = 2
    .....
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but what about operation hours like: 10:00 - 02:00 (where start is smaller than end). Im exactly stucked with this scenario and looking for other solutions for it.

Comment: Kingalione - perhaps shifting to military (24hr) time will do the trick.